# Download a brand new asset from the server: what is the best practice?

Tags: android, download, assets

My app downloads some assets from my server using an AsyncTask and I put them in a folder on the SD Card. Then, I use these assets in my buttons backgrounds. Everything works, but I'm wondering the best practice to use when I change my assets on the server side. In fact, at the moment, I'm not able to know if the server asset is a new one compared to the one stored locally. However, I was thinking about two possible solutions:
1) The app checks the server for new files, e.g. twice a day. If new files are there, then download them and upgrade the storage locally. In this case: how can I get the time difference between the local and the server file? In other words, how can I know that the server asset is a new one compared to the local one?
2) The server send a notification to the client when a new file is available. How can I manage that?

What is the best choice between the two above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an assets version number for your assets. Every time your app starts, you can request the latest assets version number. if its larger than the version number you have stored, you know that the images have changed and you can download the latest images. Every time images changes in the server, make sure you increase the version number.

You should also store the version number when you retrieve assets from the server.

Comment: Well, I think I would use this approach and accept your answer because you were the fastest one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think option 2) ("server send a notification to the client when a new file is available") would require running a Service on the client in order to "listen" to the notification --> This is overkill

What I would do is similar to your option 1) except it is independent from the client and server's clocks:

Version your assets, and store:

- On server side, in a txt or xml file, the latest version of each asset available on the server
- On client side, the current version of each asset the version number of the latest

On client side, you would then periodically retrieve the txt/xml file, and determine if you need to download new assets.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some code on the server to compute the MD5 sum of a file, and then from the Android app, make a request to e.g. http://hostname/getMD5?file=myfile.abc, and if the MD5 sum differ from the local one, download the file again.

As for notifying the phone, I don't think that's possible. But it might be OK to poll every 30 mins or so, since you only need to fetch a short string.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `version file` to your server, something simple such as like this one would work:

**version.txt:**

image001.bmp 3
image002.bmp 1
image003.bmp 1

You can download this file as first thing when you connect to server and parse it. Then if you notice a newer version on server, download updated files.